# How to create a custom BERT language model for a different language?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I want to create a language translation model using transformers. However, Tensorflow seems to only have a BERT model for English https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4 . If I want a BERT for another language, what is the best way to go about accomplishing this? Should I create a new BERT or can I train Tensorflow's own BertTokenizer on another language?

Answer (score 0):

The [Hugging Face model hub](https://huggingface.co/models) contains a plethora of pre-trained monolingual and multilingual transformers (and relevant tokenizers) which can be fine-tuned for your downstream task.

However, if you are unable to locate a suitable model for you language, then yes training from scratch is the only option. Beware though that training from scratch can be a resource-intensive task that will require significant compute power. [Here](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train) is an excellent blog post to get you started.